# Is it possible to create a .dwg (AutoCAD file) from a PDF in python?

Tags: python, pdf, automation, autocad, dwg

Extremely rookie coder here, it's not even a real part of my job, but I have some experience from school. I would like to write a script that takes inputs like the pdf file name and scale of the plan, and can then create a .dwg file from that pdf. I've looked elsewhere online but can't seem to find anything similar. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

In the very very early conceptual stage, I just need help with some modules to help me along.

Comment: you mean something like this? https://github.com/adityaintwala/Image2CAD